# Linearization of thermistor

Tags: resistance, thermistor, linear

[image]

Thermistors are highly nonlinear devices . This linearization circuit of a NTC
produces a linear response (temperature/resistance).But what should be the values of \$R_{s}\$ and \$R_{p}\$?

Image from: [TI.com](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoaa12/snoaa12.pdf?ts=1641053889653&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F#:%7E:text=There%20are%20two%20basic%20ways,output%20voltage%20is%20directly%20used).

Comment: You need to at least give credit to the authors of the illustrations. (See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.) A page reference would be helpful to anyone who has the book to get context to your question. Also, inline MathJAX tag is `\$` on EE.SE. Hit the [edit] link ... Also, I can see that you have asked many questions on the site but accepted answers to none of them. Can you address this?

Comment: I found this circuit on the Internet

Comment: Well then post the URL for the article. It still belongs to someone else and your edit still gives no context to the diagram.

Comment: https://www.edn.com/linearize-thermistors-with-new-formula/  or this https://journals.pan.pl/dlibra/publication/104341/edition/90345/content

Comment: That circuit configuration does give a fairly linear response of V vs Temp over a narrow temperature range.  But what you are giving up is sensitivity - Delta V vs Delta T.

Comment: One can also use a "software calibration" table ... Most useful ?

Answer (score 6):

For a standard NTC thermistor, make the impedance of Rs in parallel with Rp equal to the thermistor resistance at the midpoint temperature of the span you want to linearise. That will then give you excellent linearity over ± 5°C, and reasonable linearity over ± 10°C from the mid point.

Having chosen Rs//Rp equal to the midpoint resistance, you can choose Rs and Rp freely to match your supply voltage and desired sensing range. The most convenient for many applications is to dispense with Rp, make Rs equal to the midpoint temperature resistance, then your linear voltage/temperature range is equally disposed about the midpoint of your supply voltage, which is ideal for reading with an ADC that uses its rail as the voltage reference.

Comment: If Rs||Rp  = Rntc(Ti) then how can Rs  = Rntc(Ti)?

Comment: @CartoonRyan If Rs//Rp = Rntc, and Rs=Rntc, then Rp=∞, which is what 'dispense with Rp' means.

Answer (score 1):

If one wants play with a simulator as [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm), one can do it by "hand" ...

Just "click" on Rp and Rs defines, then arrows up or down. Just remember that a straight line doesn't do. For changing parameters of NTC, just click also "define beta ..." and "define Ro ...".

Ro is the value of CTN @T=To.

The FOUR functions can be done simultaneously. R2, R4, R8, R10 are the NTC.

The dotted lines are for Rp not used (2 right schematics).

[image]